# Find equivalent rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
  {'code': '0101010C0AAAAAA', 'chemical': '0101010C0', 'is_generic': True, 'format': 'AAAA'},
  {'code': '0101010C0BBAAAA', 'chemical': '0101010C0', 'is_generic': False, 'format': 'AAAA'},
  {'code': '0101010F0AAAUAU', 'chemical': '0101010F0', 'is_generic': True, 'format': 'AUAU'},
  {'code': '0101010F0BCAAAU', 'chemical': '0101010F0', 'is_generic': False, 'format': 'AAAU'},
  {'code': '0101010G0AAABAB', 'chemical': '0101010G0', 'is_generic': False, 'format': 'ABAB'}
])
                  code   chemical is_generic format
0      0101010C0AAAAAA  0101010C0       True   AAAA
1      0101010C0BBAAAA  0101010C0      False   AAAA
2      0101010F0AAAUAU  0101010F0       True   AUAU
3      0101010F0BCAAAU  0101010F0      False   AAAU
4      0101010G0AAABAB  0101010G0      False   ABAB
```

I'd like to create a new dataframe with a row for each code where `is_generic` is False. Then I'd like to add a column that for each code, is the code with the same chemical and format, but for which is_generic is True:

```
           code        generic_equiv
0101010C0BBAAAA      0101010C0AAAAAA
0101010F0BCAAAU      0101010F0AAAUAU
0101010G0AAABAB      None
```

I know how to get the dataframe with a row for each code where `is_generic` is False:

```
df1 = df[df['is_generic'] == True]
```

I guess I want to do a conditional merge with df, but how to do this?

Comment: Is there guaranteed to be at most one generic=True row matching any particular generic=False row?  Or could there be multiple generics for one non-generic?  If there could be multiple, how would the output look like?

Comment: @JohnZwinck thanks! Yes, there's at most one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here...

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
  {'code': '0101010C0AAAAAA', 'chemical': '0101010C0', 'is_generic': True, 'format': 'AAAA'},
  {'code': '0101010C0BBAAAA', 'chemical': '0101010C0', 'is_generic': False, 'format': 'AAAA'},
  {'code': '0101010F0AAAUAU', 'chemical': '0101010F0', 'is_generic': True, 'format': 'AUAU'},
  {'code': '0101010F0BCAAAU', 'chemical': '0101010F0', 'is_generic': False, 'format': 'AAAU'},
  {'code': '0101010G0AAABAB', 'chemical': '0101010G0', 'is_generic': False, 'format': 'ABAB'}
])

groups = df.groupby('is_generic')
pd.merge(groups.get_group(False), groups.get_group(True), on='chemical', how='left')
```

Output...

```
    chemical           code_x format_x is_generic_x           code_y format_y  \
0  0101010C0  0101010C0BBAAAA     AAAA        False  0101010C0AAAAAA     AAAA   
1  0101010F0  0101010F0BCAAAU     AAAU        False  0101010F0AAAUAU     AUAU   
2  0101010G0  0101010G0AAABAB     ABAB        False              NaN      NaN   

  is_generic_y  
0         True  
1         True  
2          NaN
```

Subset/rename columns as you wish.

Comment: Thanks - that seems to work! I did `on=['chemical', 'format']` to match on both columns.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new dataframe where only the false are present and merge the 2 new dataframes seperatly

```
df1 = df[df['is_generic'] == True]  
df2 = df[df['is_generic'] == False]  
df3 = pd.merge(df1[['chemical','code']],df2[['chemical','code']],left_on='chemical',right_on='chemical',how='right')
del df3['chemical']
df3.rename(columns={'code_x':'generic_equiv','code_y':'code'},inplace=True)
```

output:

```
  generic_equiv             code
0  0101010C0AAAAAA  0101010C0BBAAAA
1  0101010F0AAAUAU  0101010F0BCAAAU
2              NaN  0101010G0AAABAB
```